# passing array of structs from c# to regular dll

Tags: c#, arrays, data-structures

I have a regular dll with the following function exported.

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int FindNearestStuff(double _latitude, double _longitude , LocationStruct * locations[])
```

LocationStruct is very simple

```
struct LocationStruct
  {
   long positionIndex;
   long item;
  };
```

I'm tryign to call it from c# using

```
 [DllImport("myclever.dll", CharSet = CharSet.None)]
        private static extern int FindNearestStuff(double _latitude, double _longitude, 
                                                    ref LocationStruct [] locations);
```

It's all cool and funky and I can step into the dll function from the debugger.
Inside the dll the LocationStruct array is populated correctly and all is very good.

The problem I have is when it returns back from the dll, the LocationStruct array is not coming back with the data - just empty values...

What am I missing?

Comment: struct LocationStruct
  {
   long roadIndex;
   long tdist;
  };


and in c#
internal  struct LocationStruct
  {
   public int roadIndex;  //its a long in the C code
   public int tdist;//its a long in the C code
  };

Comment: I don't think P/Invoke can handle double indirection here (array passed by `ref` on C# side, pointer-to-pointer on C++ side). Do you actually need it; won't a pointer to first element in the array of structs do in C++?

Comment: Easiest way I can think of is to use unsafe C#. Also remember to use StructLayout.Sequential

Comment: All C# structs are implicitly `Sequential`.

Comment: thanks Pavel; that just saved me a lot of typing!

Comment: i tried it without the ref keyword..and the code runs obviously but the returned array of structures still doesnt have the data added :(

Buzz

Comment: If you remove the `ref` keyword be sure to add `[In,Out]` attributes on the array parameter so that data is marshaled both ways (`ref` adds those implicitly).

Comment: Also if you remove `ref`, don't forget that you don't need the `[]` in your C function prototype as well.

Answer (score 2):

thanks so much for your help - you certainly put me onthe right direction and i really appreciate your assistance!

This is the solution which seems to work for me;

```
[DllImport("myclever.dll", CharSet = CharSet.None)]
        private static extern int FindNearestStuff(double _latitude, double _longitude,  IntPtr locations);


public static int FindNearestStuff(double _latitude, double _longitude, LocationStruct[] locations)
        {
            int returnValue = -1;
            LocationStruct temp;
            temp.roadIndex = 1;
            temp.tdist = 1;
            int iStructSize = Marshal.SizeOf(temp);
            try
            {
                IntPtr locationsPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

                IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(iStructSize * 10);
                FindNearestRoads(_latitude, _longitude,  buffer);
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(buffer.ToInt32() + iStructSize * i);
                    locations[i] = (LocationStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(LocationStruct));

                }

                returnValue = 0;
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
```

Comment: and of course dont forget to

 Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);

!

Comment: If that works for you, you indeed had one level of indirection too much in your original code, just like Pavel hinted. You don't have to do all this allocation and copying yourself, you should be able to take your original function declaration and just remove the ref modifier on the array parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you will be able to do this automatically since C# has no way of knowing how many items are returned in the locations variable (I'm assuming that the return value of FindNearestStuff is the number of entries in locations.)

You will have to manually marshal your data using the [Marshall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.aspx) class and a process like this:

```
[DllImport("myclever.dll", CharSet = CharSet.None)]
private static extern int FindNearestStuff(double _latitude, double _longitude, 
                                           out IntPtr locations);

public static LocationStruct[] FindNearestStuff(double latitude, double longitude) {
    IntPtr locationsPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
    int numLocations = FindNearestStuff(latitude, longitude, out locationsPtr);

    LocationsStruct[] locations = new LocationsStruct[numLocations];

    for (int i = 0; i < numLocations; i++) {

          // locationsPtr is a pointer to the struct, so read the value
          // at locationPtr which will be the address of the struct and
          // then manually marshal the struct from that address
          locaitonsStruct[i] = (LocationStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
              Marshal.ReadIntPtr(locationsPtr), typeof(LocationsStruct));

          // Move to the location pointer to the next address of a 
          // pointer to a struct
          locationsPtr += IntPtr.Size;  
    }

    return locations;
}
```

I haven't actually tried this so caveat emptor.